# How to get properties of a field of table in sybase

Tags: sybase

Here is details

In sybase, I have a table "abc" having 5 fields(name, roll, address, desc,path). If i would use 'sp_help tablename' then i can see all properties of all fields how i can get properties of a particular field i.e. roll or any one field and their properties using sql or pl/sql.

As we know that we can not use any parameters in sp_help so is there any way to to get the properties of a field, (pl/sql or sql)?
Thanks in advance

```
sp_help tablename
```

Comment: Hi, I see you have logged into SO recently but have not accepted my answer.  Please remember to accept answers, so people can get credit for helping.  If there are any problems with my answer, please let me know, so I can resolve them.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on what specific properties you are looking for.  Assuming you are looking for Table, Column, Datatype, Datatype Length - you have to join `sysobjects`, `syscolumns`, and `systypes`

```
use YOURDB
go

select o.name, c.name, t.usertype, c.length
from
  sysobject o,
  syscolumns c,
  systypes t
where       o.id = c.id
  and c.usertype = t.usertype
  and o.name like "YOUR_TABLE"
  and c.name like "YOUR_COLUMN"
go
```

If you want more than that, you'll have to bring in other columns and/or tables into the query like `sysdepends`, `sysdefaults` or `sysconstraints`

More information about the system tables can be found here:
[Sybase ASE Reference Manual: Tables > System Tables](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc36274.1550/html/tables/CEGBFEGJ.htm)

And the system table diagram, which shows the column mappings can be found here:
http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc70204.1550/pdf/a155pst.pdf

Also, FYI - Sybase uses T-SQL (like SQL Server), not pl/sql.